# Acumatica reports "Invalid column names from JAMS tables" error

Tags: acumatica

We have Manufacturing package version "MFG - 19.102.0051.25 - 2019.05.06" published in our instance. Along with this we have our own customization package. We recently developed a process screen which brings in data from ARRegister and ARTran tables. We also have some custom fields created in ARTran table, on process button action we are doing some calculations and storing values in custom fields of ARTran table.

We are not using any Manufacturing related fields in this process screen. The issue is when do process the records we are getting error saying Invalid column names from JAMS tables. What might cause this issue? See the attached screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut4MQ.png

Answer (score 0):

I have dirty hack for you to use.
I'd suggest you to create columns, for lack of which code complains and execute your process again.
Overall it could be that some package has dependency from that fields, or may have in the future.